# How to get a bootstrap resource in a controller plugin in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
protected function _initDatabase()
{
     $params = array(
            'host'     => '',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'dbname'   => '',
        );

    $database = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', $params);
    $database->getConnection();
    return $database;
}
```

.

```
class App_Controller_Plugin_Test extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
    {
        // how i get database?

    }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can always get a reference to the front controller:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
```

From that you can get the bootstrap:

```
$bootstrap = $front->getParam("bootstrap");
```

From the bootstrap you can get bootstrap plugins:

```
if ($bootstrap->hasPluginResource("database")) {
      $dbResource = $bootstrap->getPluginResource("database");
}
$db = $dbResource->getDatabase();
```

But that's a lot of extra plumbing!

Honestly, you'd be better off storing the database adapter object in the registry during your bootstrap:

```
protected function _initDatabase()
{
     $params = array(
            'host'     => '',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'dbname'   => '',
        );

    $database = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', $params);
    $database->getConnection();
    Zend_Registry::set("database", $database);
    return $database;
}
```

Then you can get the database adapter anywhere:

```
Zend_Registry::get("database");
```

See also my answer to [What is the “right” Way to Provide a Zend Application With a Database Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735534/what-is-the-right-way-to-provide-a-zend-application-with-a-database-handler/1735683#1735683)

Comment: Why does getResource("db") works in my case and not getResource("database") ?

Comment: It just uses a key according to the resource name you wrote in your bootstrap config file.  For example if prefix your config params with `resource.db` then it will use `db`.

Answer (score 6):

Too bad there's nothing like `Zend_Controller_Action`'s `getInvokeArg("bootstrap")` in a plugin. You could always get the bootstrap reference through the front controller:

```
$db = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam("bootstrap")->getResource("database");
```

But what I usually do is

```
Zend_Registry::set('database', $database);
```

and then in your plugin:

```
try 
{
    $db = Zend_Registry::get('database');
}
catch (Zend_Exception $e)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Easier, and database can be retrieved pretty much anywhere in the application.

Answer (score 5):

[I need to check this against some working code on another machine. I believe it's something like this...]

```
$db = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('db');
```

Answer (score 0):

$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();