# Zend default adapter not available when using just config

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

I'm using application.ini to bootstrap DB settings and adapter in Zend 1.12

```
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "server"
resources.db.params.port = "3310"
resources.db.params.username = "user"
resources.db.params.password = "pass"
resources.db.params.dbname = "dbname"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

However, I can't find default adapter in my scripts:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```

This is giving empty result.

I must use init mentod in Bootstrap to get it working:

```
protected function _initDbTable() {

        $resource = $this->getPluginResource('db');
        $adapter = $resource->getDbAdapter();
        Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($adapter);
    }
```

Is there any way to setup all just in application.ini ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it right. Resources in config need to be bootstrapped just like how you do it.
"Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($adapter);" because that's what "resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true" for.

See also [What is the "right" Way to Provide a Zend Application With a Database Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735534/what-is-the-right-way-to-provide-a-zend-application-with-a-database-handler/1735683#1735683)